# How to change just the title bar color KDE Plasma

Tags: kde-plasma

I'm running Pop!_OS 19.10 with KDE Plasma (5.16.5).  I am using the Breeze Dark theme (which comes standard with Pop).

I just want to change the title bar color, but I am not sure how this is done.  I don't want to break the existing theme, but I'm not sure how to clone an existing theme if that's possible.

Where in the theme file/folder directory is the title bar specified?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486489) answer might be useful to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer referenced by Roj worked for me.

Created: **/home/UserA/.local/usera.colors** which contains:

```
[General]
Name=UserA_TitlebarTheme

[WM]
activeBackground=140,69,211
inactiveBackground=80,40,120
```

Kudos to Roj!